# Find and Replace ALL using a Readline Value in r script

Tags: r, replace

I have an script file with several lines of code that works perfectly.

Now I'm trying to use it more intensively so I'd like to introduce a question at the beginning of the script  and then use the value of the question (answer) and replace some parts of my code with the answer value.

Something like this:

```
readline(prompt = "Question 1?: ")
#user input = Y
#Find "X" (previous value in my code lines) and Replace All with "Y"
```

Then re-run my code with the new "Y" value in and get the results, so the re-run I assume should be executed starting after the line with the Replace All.

Is that possible? Maybe gsub?

Any comments will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to include your code to get more specific help.  At the very least, include a small reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with a simplified version of what you're trying to do.

Comment: You are right. Let me prepare a small example. Thanks ;-)